# Proof: $\arg\left(\bar z\right) = -\arg\left( z\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to prove that $\arg\left(\bar z\right) = -\arg\left( z\right)$ and a few other properties of the complex numbers. I'm being able to prove the others with no problem, but I just don't see where to start this one from. I find it kind of obvious but don't know how to prove it.

We have $z=a+bi$ and $\bar z=a-bi$, $z$ being a complex number.

Therefore the arguments are $\arg(z)=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ and $\arg(\bar z)=\arctan\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)$

Any hint on how to approach this?

Comment: How do you define the complex conjugate ? How do you define the argument ?

Comment: We have $z=a+bi$ and $\bar z=a-bi$ therefore the arguments are $Arg(z)=arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ and $Arg(\bar z)=arctan\left(\frac{-b}{a}\right)$

Comment: You solved then, what more do you want ?

Comment: I feel like I'm not being explicit enough. So it should be enought with that and making clear that $arctan(-a)=-arctan(a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=r e^{0\theta}$ so $Arg(z)=\theta$, then $\bar z=r e^{-i\theta} \implies Arg(\bar z)=-\theta$. This proves that $Arg(\bar z)=-Arg(z)$

Comment: We have not covered $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$ or the exponential notation yet, so the proof will not need to use that fact or notation.

Comment: This is called the polar form of complex number which is essential to the concept of Arg.

Comment: We covered that today, thanks for the answer, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the $\arg$ function is not precisely defined, this question cannot be answered. For example, if you define the argument to be an angle in range $(0,2\pi]$, it is clear that it is impossible for

$$\arg(a)=-\arg(b)$$ to hold.